# Javascript - Functions with vars/params

Tags: javascript, function, variables, arguments

I'm getting trouble working with functions and parameters

The issue is that i have my function and i work with a var called contacts that is full of stuff:

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // specify contact search criteria
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter = "";      // empty search string returns all contacts
        options.multiple = true;  // return multiple results
        filter = ["displayName","phoneNumbers"]; // return contact.displayName field    displayName

        // find contacts
        navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
    //
    function onSuccess(contacts) {

      for (i=0;i<contacts.length;i++) {
        //window.alert("ID = " + contacts[i].id);
        document.write(contacts[i].displayName);
        tel = contacts[i].phoneNumbers;
        if (tel== null){
document.write("Sense telefon");
        }else{
                for (j=0;j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length;j++) {
            if (contacts[i].phoneNumbers != null &&
contacts[i].phoneNumbers != 'undefined') {
                document.write(" "+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value);
            }
        }
        }

        document.write('<button id='+i+' onClick="reply_click(this.id,contacts);">Borrar</button>');
        document.write(contacts[i].id);
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
    };
```

And I've the other function:

function reply_click(clicked_id,contacts)
{

```
window.alert(clicked_id);
window.alert(contacts);
 for (i=0;i<contacts.length;i++) {
 if(i==clicked_id){
 try{
    contacts[i].remove;
    window.alert("Contacte Borrat");
    }catch(err){
    window.alert(err);
    }
    }
 }
```

}

I need to work with contact object in the `reply_click` function but I can't make it work. How can i pass this var to my function ? Thanks

Comment: WTH does `ContactFindOptions` do, create an empty object? And notice that your `filter` variable is implicitly global.

Comment: You [may not use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) in an asynchronous handler.

Comment: This is stuff for work with contacts in Phonegap3, but my problem is about javascript concepts and the thing I explain in the question.

Comment: I see now. Still, try not to use `document.write`, and install the click event handlers properly (instead of an inline-attribute code string), then it will work with `contacts` in the right scope.

Comment: Could you give me an example ?

Comment: `var button = document.createElement("button"); button.id = i; button.onclick = function() { reply_click(this.id, contacts); }; // append button to DOM`